# Terminology describing two related noncommutative functions

Tags: function, terminology

I know there must be a concise term for this, but I can't seem to google my way to it.  I am looking for a word or technical term which describes two functions which are non-commutative

```
f(a,b) != f(b,a)
g(a,b) != g(b,a)
```

but have a relationship whereby:

```
f(a,b) = g(b,a)
g(a,b) = f(b,a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was kind of looking for a way to say *"f and g are _________ functions"*

I suppose it will suffice to say *"g is the transpose of f"*